# Is there a way to only run npm scripts for installed packages (opposite of --ignore-scripts)

Tags: npm, post-install

I am in a situation where I need to ship `node_modules` with the rest of my code because the destination machines do not have access to our private network (and our private npm repository).

My problem is that I want to execute everything that happens **after npm downloads all the files** so that individual packages can build themselves correctly for the target machine. Is there a way to accomplish this? Here are a couple other ways to phrase this question:

- How can I run `npm install`, but skip the download step?
- How can I run `postinstall` for installed node_modules only?

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it figured it out. There were a couple of important steps to make this happen:

When we get ready to package our code for distribution, we download all of the npm dependencies with the `--ignore-scripts` and `--no-bin-links` option. This prevents any packages from building/compiling or linking any bin files. This is effectively **only downloading** the node_modules.

```
npm install --omit=dev --ignore-scripts --no-bin-links
```

We then distribute our code to the target machine and run the following command so that any compilations and bin links happen on the target machine:

```
npm rebuild
```